# 3D Box in Pure CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I create the 3D Box with pure CSS?

[image: 3D White Cube ith Black Border]

Comment: pseudo-element or SVG. SVG as background-image would properly would be the easiest way.

Comment: First of all, create 2d planes of all 6 sides (using each div tag) of the cube (3D Box). Wrap all of those div tags in another container (div tag). For this parent div tag, try transform (rotate and translate) css properties. You can get a 3D Box as shown in your image.
Check the following tutorial, it might be helpful for you:
https://3dtransforms.desandro.com/box

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### CSS 2D Transforms

You need to play around with [skew()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/skew()) method and [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to achieve it.

```css
body {
  --border: 4px;
  --width: 400px;
  --height: 100px;
  --outline: 12px;
  --translate: 8px;
  --skew-angle: 45deg;
}

.border {
  border: var(--border) solid black;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.box {
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
}

.bottom-outline {
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--outline);
  border-top-width: 0px !important;
  transform: skew(var(--skew-angle)) translateX(var(--translate));
}

/* height would be implicitly same as box */
.right-outline {
  width: var(--outline);
  border-left-width: 0 !important;
  border-bottom-width: 0 !important;
  transform: skew(0deg, var(--skew-angle)) translateY(var(--translate));
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="box border"></div>
    <div class="right-outline border"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-outline border"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks very much!